# How to cache paginated data redis and mongodb nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongoose, caching, redis, pagination

Suppose, I have Users collection in Mongodb and their Services Collection.

And a User can have many services which are stored inside Services Collection with a ref to User.

When a request is made to get a User's profile I want the users services also. But paginated.

Now, it's easy to paginate User data but since, services data is array and paginated how to cache it so that I am able to delete it later on if services changes.

Like if I cache services like
Key = userId_pageNo

How do I know later on how many pages of data I have caches and needs to be updated or deleted

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB supports [Pipelines in Lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#join-conditions-and-uncorrelated-sub-queries) since v3.6.

You can run an aggregation pipeline on Users and do a lookup on Services. In the lookup piepline, you can specify [`$skip`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/skip/) and [`$limit`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/limit/) to paginate the services returned in the array.

Something like:

```js
Users.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      _id: userId
    }
  },
  { $lookup: {
    from: 'Services',
    as: 'services',
    let: { userId: '$_id' },
    pipeline: [
      { $match: {
        $expr: { $eq: [ '$obj_id', '$$user' ] }
      }},
      { $skip: pageNumber * itemCount },
      { $limit: itemCount }
    ]
  } }
])
```

Comment: My issue is caching. I have implemented pagination already.